# International School vs. Full Immersion

Tags: education, norway

We have two middle school aged children who we'll be moving to Norway with in a few months and we are considering schooling options. In the town we're moving to (Bergen) there are international schools where they can continue their academic careers in English and then there are the local public schools which will get them up to speed on Norwegian before plunging them into the regular curriculum.

We will be in Norway at least 3 years, possibly more.

My question is this: what are the plusses and minuses to each of the two possible approaches to their schooling?

Comment: If you haven't yet, you might look and/or post on [parenting.se].

Comment: I'd definitely go with the immersion approach, but that's just my own opinion based on my own experience. Three years can turn into more than three years surprisingly fast and those language skills will only be a benefit in the short term or the long term.